# Android Event with Reminder shows two entries in calendar application

Tags: android, google-calendar-api, reminders

Hi I am developing calendar feature in my application. I have done this in following way:

```
    fun generateEvent(context: Context, calendarId: String?,
                      eventTitle: String, eventDescription: String,
                      startTime: Long, endTime: Long)
    {
        if(!calendarId.isNullOrEmpty()){
            val cv = ContentValues()
            cv.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, calendarId)
            cv.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, eventTitle)
            cv.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, eventDescription)
            cv.put(
                CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART,
                startTime
            )
        cv.put(
            CalendarContract.Events.DTEND,
            endTime
        )
            cv.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, TimeZone.getDefault().id)
            cv.put(CalendarContract.Events.HAS_ALARM, true)
            val contentResolver: ContentResolver = context.getContentResolver()
            contentResolver.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, cv)

            var eventUri = contentResolver.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, cv)
            var eventID = eventUri?.getLastPathSegment()?.toLong()
            if(eventID != null){
                val reminderCV = ContentValues()
                reminderCV.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.EVENT_ID, eventID)
                reminderCV.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.MINUTES, 1)
                reminderCV.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.METHOD, CalendarContract.Reminders.METHOD_ALERT)
                contentResolver.insert(CalendarContract.Reminders.CONTENT_URI, reminderCV)
            }
        }
    }
```

It generate the event and reminder on google calendar. Only issue is that it shows two entries on calendar. One is with reminder and other one without reminder.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two insert statements. Just remove the

```
contentResolver.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, cv)
```

and your code works fine